# Kerberos Delegation problems when sites are on the same machine

Tags: iis, active-directory, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication, kerberos-delegation

I have one server that hosts two sites, one is a webapi site and another is wcf site like below, the **identity** is the wcf site, the **sql** is the webapi site:

[IIS Sites Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EVWN.png)

And I set accounts for both of them as their App pool identity

> identity site -> kerberos\identity
>
> sql site -> kerberos\sql

and both of the sites use **Windows Authentication**, and the sql site also enable **Asp.Net Impersonation**, also enable the **useAppPoolIdentity** in **system.webServer.authentication.windowsAuthentication** and **Impersonate user after authentication** in **Local Security Policies**.

The two accounts have set SPNs and Delegation in AD, like:
[Sql Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6ial.png)  and [Identity Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuXB3.png)

Now, my sql site must call the service in identity site, impersonate the user to call the service, but I fail to impersonate the user. In sql site, I use **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity** to get the user and the user is right, but in **identity** site, using **Thread.Principle.Identity** always get the **sql** site App pool identity. I don't know why it fails.

In the webapi code, I use

```
using((HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity).Impersonate())
{
    callService();
}
```

or

```
WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated((HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity).AccessToken, () =>
 {
       callService();
 });
```

Both not works, I have succeed this process in previous environment but this is not, it always fail when calling the **identity site service**.

And I setup this environment for simulating the procedure of AAD App Proxy to confirm that our webapi project can call the wcf service with the exact user in our production environment. The test environments are on the local Hyper-V, also the AD controller.

Comment: Do you get any information when you use using Thread.Principle.Identity to get the identity site?

Comment: @samwu yes, the app pool account...

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @samwu I mean, it always use the domain account set in app pool as the user to access the site... And today I change the background from dotnet fx 4.8 to dotnet 6, then it works normally...